# Can't convert to DDS file because width and height are not multiples of four

Tags: adobe-photoshop, starcraft2, image-formats, dds

I'm trying to convert a JPEG image to a DDS file format in Adobe Photoshop CC; when I keep saving it keeps showing me a message that says:

> image width and height must be multiple of four

The image I'm trying to use is 2000 x 1330, image size is 2.86 MB. What does this mean? And how can I make this work?

I'm using the NVIDIA plug in. What does this mean — I need six images side by side and width should equal height. Must the height be in powers of two?

Answer (score 2):

> image width and height must be multiple of four

*2000 / 4 = 500

1330 / 4 = 332.5*

So, your height is not in multiples of four. You need 1332 or 1328 as height in order to be able to convert it.

Comment: You're welcome. Since you are new to Super User – if this answered your question, you can mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the green checkmark next to it: http://superuser.com/help/someone-answers